# How to pass parameter DataTable from mvc application to web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I need to pass DataTable as  parameters from my MVC application to web api.

I am looking some code as

```
 public void ConvertToSomeType(DataTable dt)

 {
 /*This code would be on mvc application 
 }


 public HttpActionResult GetData(SomeType st)
{

/*Here method should be convert sometype to DataTable*/

}
```

So I Expected same DataTable which send from mvc application and same DataTable receive in webapi

Source table created like as following

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 dt.column.add("Id");
 dt.column.add("Name");
 dt.rows.add("1","abc");
 dt.rows.add("1","abc");
```

Expected same DataTable in webapi

```
public HttpActionResult GetData(SomeType st)
{

DataTable dt = SomeMethod(st);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one option with below steps,

**1)** Serialize your DataTable to JSON from MVC Controller like,

```
public ActionResult GetDatatable()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Id");
    dt.Columns.Add("Name");
    dt.Rows.Add("1", "abc");
    dt.Rows.Add("1", "abc");

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);

    //Call the Web API Controller action method with above string parameter via WebRequest or HttpClient
}
```

**2)** Deserialize incoming string json back to DataTable like,

```
public IHttpActionResult GetData(string json)
{
    DataTable dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(json);
}
```

**Note:** You need to install NuGet package for newtonsoft.json by using below command in package manager console

```
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 12.0.1
```